# How to search a CSV file and return multiple entries based on keyword input

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

Hello I have a CSV file that has Name, Extension, and Cell. Some users have both extensions and a cell number. I am trying to create a search on our intranet page where a user will enter a keyword (name, ext or cell) and then return all the results that have the keyword in it. I read in a CSV file using fgetcsv but I was only able to return extensions. If I searched for a name or a cell number it would return a blank white page. here is the code I have:

```
$value = $_POST["search"];
$file = 'phonelist/PhonelistCSV2.csv';
while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE){
    //print_r($data); - this was just a test to see the data printing out. It prints the entire CSV
    print_r(array_keys($data,$value));
}
fclose($file);
```

I gave up on fgetcsv after an entire day of googling and trying to get it working. Now I am trying taking the CSV and encoding it to JSON with

```
$csv=file_get_contents($file); $array=array_map("str_getcsv", explode ("\n",$csv)); 
$json=json_encode($array);
```

I printed out the json array to verify that the contents were the same as the csv. The I created a javascript function to search for a keyword. I was testing with putting the value in a div just for testing purposes but I can't get the function to work

```
$value = $_POST["search"];
$keyword=json_encode($value);
<script type="text/javascript">
function search(keyword){
return json.filter(({name, ext, cell}) => {
    return name.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
           ext.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
           cell.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) > -1 
})
}
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = json; // I tried it this way and
alert(search($keyword);
</script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

so long story short, I need some help in creating a search for my intranet to search a CSV office directory with names, extension and cell numbers. so far, in the solutions I've tried I've only been able to return extension numbers. I would like it to function like, search for "Tim", return all people with Tim in their name and their subsequent extension, cell # or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do a case insensitive search on something like the name, and filter your records accordingly.

The first part just gets the csv data into an array.

```
<?php

$data =<<<DATA
Neil Buchanan,334,012345678
Tony Hart,314,01234828828
Henri Matisse,392,01234457575
DATA;

$data = array_map('str_getcsv', preg_split('/\R/',$data));

$name_search = function($keyword) use ($data) {
    return array_filter($data, function($line) use ($keyword) {
        return stristr($line[0], $keyword);
    });
};

$results = $name_search('to');
var_export($results);
echo "Next Search\n";
$results = $name_search('he');
var_export($results);
```

Output:

```
array (
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 'Tony Hart',
      1 => '314',
      2 => '01234828828',
    ),
  )Next Search
  array (
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => 'Henri Matisse',
      1 => '392',
      2 => '01234457575',
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried using your code but when I ran it all it returned was array(). I tried it first using the post value from $value. then I tried as you did and entered the characters in to the function directly. either way it returned array().

Comment: @SkylarP perhaps you could post a sample of your csv file, or dump some of your data once you have translated it from csv?  `var_export(array_slice($data, 0, 2));`.  Are you searching the right column?

Comment: You can see see the same code with different input data working here: https://3v4l.org/dRXev

Comment: thank you I was able to tailor your code to fit my search needs. really appreciate all your help.